# Thread freezes when calling [NSManagedObjectContext save:]

Tags: ios, multithreading, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm using a sqlite file to save my App's log. To synchronize multiple threads, I used a singleton object and @synchronized this object that only one thread can save the log one time. The NSManagedObjectContext's object is the member of the log object singleton.

I've encountered a problem that when there are many threads saving their log, one thread freezes when calling [NSManagedObjectContext save:]. No other threads can enter the @synchronized zone, and that causes all these threads freezes. I tried to low down the frequency of calling save: method (for example, call save: once when 10 threads finished saving their log), and the issue happens less. I'm sure the formating of the data is correct, since I tried to log more than once of a entry, and the freeze happens in the middle.

Have you encountered this issue before. If so, how to solve the issue? It seems that using my way can low down the frequency, but it's only a walk around. I wish to know the reason why App freezes when calling [NSManagedObjectContext save:].

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only one thread should be making updates to the managed object context and saving (at least at any one time). Create an `NSOperationQueue` in your singleton, set it to only run a single operation at a time and then add each log via a new `NSOperation` (probably by block).

Comment: I used @synchronized to let only one thread update NSManagedObjectContext, so actually there's only one thread calling  [NSManagedObjectContext save:] each time. The problem is that if this method is called too frequently, it will be frozen randomly.